# Create a contact form

Tags: php, html

I am having issues with a contact form in the website I am working. My `php` file where the code to send the mail is run does not work. When the user clicks  the submit button it shows in the screen the code and does not send the email.

**HTML**

```
<header class="body1">
</header>

<section class="body1">
</section>

<footer class="body1">
</footer>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<h2>Envie uma mensagem ou faça um pedido</h2>
<label>Nome:</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Digite seu nome...">

<label>Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Digite seu email...">

<label>Mensagem:</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'De: Babylon Store'; 
$to = 'my@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Novo pedido';

$body = "De: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Sua mensagem foi enviada!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Aconteceu algo errado. Por favor tente novamente!</p>'; 
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What does it display after you click submit? Also, you need to close the `<form>` tag.

Comment: You do have html and body tags in your html, right? Any errors?

Comment: The form is closed, it was not formatted properly

Comment: The closing form tag I forgot to put here. When I click submit it shows the php code in the browser.

Comment: Do you have a server running PHP?

Comment: Yes, I have all the tags, I just posted here the part that involves the contact form itself.

Comment: I'm not talking about tags. The fact that it's just displaying the PHP code makes me think that you don't have PHP running on your server. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: 3 advices, 1- put your post variables inside if post, 2- check $_POST[submit] with isset and 3-put your send mail into try catch block and see what happends

Comment: Setup a local mail server for receiving a mail for this purpose we
Use Smtp4dev mail server.
Problem 1 may occur  during this stage is php mail function sendmail_from() is not set in php.ini file.
Set it to sendmail_from=localhost from [;sendmail_from].
Problem 2 that may occur after setting php.ini file is 
      Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port". 
For this purpose we used smtp4dev local mail server after website comes online this problem  would not ocuur.
it helped me may for you too..

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Sua mensagem foi enviada!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Aconteceu algo errado. Por favor tente novamente!</p>'; 
}
}
see may this work

Comment: PHP tags (<?php) and code being displayed is a dead ringer for **PHP NOT INSTALLED CORRECTLY (OR AT ALL)**. The possible causes for this are too many to list, and depend on what your server is, what platform, which 'flavour' of PHP (fastCGI, plain CGI, module, ...) and others. Check out http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/install.php

Comment: The problem is on the server. I am gonna check it out, thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the codes myself and it doesn't work.

Never used: **if(mail)**, try using **mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)**

Although, the contact form you're currently working on isn't safe at all. Many bots can submit the form automatically and can send you numerous of spam emails. The way to prevent these, is to use a security captcha verification which totally prevents these bots from submitting your form. If you're interested in a secured form, get in touch with me as I'll write one for you **free-of-charge** :)

I know there is a way where you can process mails using **if(mail)** statements, but there's numerous scripts like PHPMailer which can do the trick for you easily. If you're processing this contact-form on a web-server, then it's most likely to be in their hosting-configuration faults. If you're using Localhost (eg: WAMP), try doing that way to ensure if it works on your self-set server, if it does then it's most likely to be a faulty web-server you're currently running on.

> **PS:** I'm a PHP Script Developer, developed more than 25 scripts.